# Converting measurement program. If statement says ; expected?

Tags: java

Please could someone take a look at my code. It won't compile because it says ; expected here - }elseif (convert == 2){.

I don't understand why, I'm pretty new to this.
Regards.

//user chooses what unit of measurments to convert, inputs number and displays conversion.

```
class Convertweight
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Declare variables
        double feet=0.0, temp=0.0, weight=0.0, metres=0.0, f=0.0, stone=0.0, convert=0.0;


        //choices of measurment to convert
        System.out.println("Please choose and enter either 1,2 or 3 from the measurements below.");
        System.out.println("1. Feet to metres");
        System.out.println("2. C temp to F temp");
        System.out.println("3. KG to stone");
        convert=input.nextDouble();

        //convert measurment if option 1 is chosen.
     if (convert == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter measurement");
        feet=input.nextDouble();
        metres=feet/3.28;
        System.out.println(metres + "m"); 

        //convert temperature if option 2 is chosen.
     } elseif (convert == 2){
            System.out.println("Enter temperature in celsius");
            temp=input.nextDouble();
            F=C*1.8+32;
            System.out.println(F + "f");

         //convert weight if option 3 is chosen.  
     } elseif (convert == 3){
            System.out.println("Enter weight in KG");
            weight=input.nextDouble();
            stone=weight/6.35029318;
            System.out.println(stone+"st");


    }
```

Comment: `elseif ` should be `else if ` is it a typo while posting code here or this is your real code?

Comment: `elseif` is PHP syntax, not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`else if` is the correct format `elseif` will cause a compilation error. check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) for better understanding.